# Lower bound for sum of a multiplicative function based on lower bound on value of primes

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-function

Let $f$ be a non-negative multiplicative function. Suppose we have some bound on $\sum_{p \le x} f(p)$, where the summation is over primes. Is it possible to give a lower bound on $\sum_{n \le x} f(n)$ that is better than the trivial bound $\sum_{n \le x} f(n) \ge \sum_{p \le x} f(p)$? Or perhaps if we assume some control of $f(p^k)$.

It seems like this type of problem ought to be have been investigated before, but I'm not sure where to look. I haven't been even able to save a factor of $\log x$.

Comment: What is your real problem and $f(n)$ ? There are things like for $f$ completely multiplicative $\sum_{p \le x} f(p)=\text{Li}(x) + O(x^{1-\epsilon}) \implies  \sum_{n \le x} f(n) = Cx +  O(x^{1-\epsilon})$. In general $\sum_{n \le x} f(n) = \sum_{k \le \log_2(x)}\frac{1}{k!} \frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}h^k(x)$ where $h^k$ is the $k$-fold Mellin convolution of $h(x)$ with itself.

Comment: @reuns The exact problem is difficult to describe. I am able to show that the number of connected components in a certain family of graphs (depending on $n$) is $\ge$ some multiplicative function.

Comment: How do you get $\sum_n\ge\sum_p$? Is there some assumption you are not telling us about (like, $flge0$)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are correct, I forgot to mention that

Comment: If you are satisfied with one or another of the answers, you can click in the check box next to the answer to "accept" it. If you are not satisfied, you can ask for further explication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example where I don't think you can save a factor of $\log x$. Let $f(p)=p!$, $f(p^k)=0$ for $k\ge2$. The sum over the primes is comparable to $x!$. The sum over the nonprimes is bounded by $(2x)(x/2)!$, which is tiny compared to the sum over the primes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no analytic number theorist, but here's a (very basic) attempt:

Let $F(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}f(x)$ and $P(x)=\sum'_{p<x} f(p)$
where the second summation is over primes. You want to say something non-trivial about the relationship between $F(x)$ and $P(x)$.

Two things: If your $f(p)$ are all non-negative, then you should be able to use that the prime powers in $[0,x]$ are quite scarce and probably just using products of two primes you should be able to save something.

That is, the contribution from numbers $n\in [0,x]$ that are products of two primes is lower bounded by $$\left(\sum_{0<p\leq \sqrt x}f(p)\right)^2-\sum_{0<p<\sqrt{x}}f(p)^2+\sum_{0<p\leq x}f(p^2)  =\left[P(\sqrt x)\right]^2-\sum_{0<p<\sqrt{x}}f(p)^2+\sum_{0<p\leq x}f(p^2)  $$

If the middle sum left at the very end is very small (for instance if $0<f(x)<1$), then this method might be useful. Or more generally, if you know some relation between $f(p)^2$ and $f(p^2)$, you can easily figure out if this heuristic will help. In particular, if the values are roughly the same, the $P(x)^2$ is your saving.